# How to add a condition in registration controller to check if the email already exists?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

This API is called when the user tries to register and enter the details. I am looking to see if I can add a condition that says email already exists.

I think I need something like:

```js
      const user = await User.find({ email })
      if (user) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: "User with this already exists" })
      }
```

But I am creating a new user, so where should I place the above query. I'm kind of confused with the order of execution.

```js
module.exports = {
    registerUser: async(req, res, next) => {
      try {
        var {
          username,
          email,
          password
        } = req.body
        if (password) {
          const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
          password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
        }
        if (!username || !email || !password) {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({
              message: "Username, email and password are must"
            })
        }
        if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            message: "Invaid email"
          })
        }
        if (password.length < 6) {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({
              message: "Password should be of at least 6 characters"
            })
        }
        const user = await User.create({
          username,
          email,
          password
        })
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(404).json({
            error: "No user found "
          })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
          user
        })
      } catch (error) {
        return next(error)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution will be to place it before any logic, also I changed `res.json` in `if` block to `throw` because `throw` stops execution of code below but `res.json` continues and that can cause potential problems. Also, I change `Module.find()` to `Module.findOne()` because `find()` returns empty array if nothing was found and `if([emptyArray]`) returns `true`

```
module.exports = {
    registerUser: async(req, res, next) => {
      try {
        var {
          username,
          email,
          password
        } = req.body
        const user = await User.findOne({
          email
        })
        if (user) {
          throw 'User with this already exists'
        }
        if (password) {
          const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
          password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
        }
        if (!username || !email || !password) {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({
              message: "Username, email and password are must"
            })
        }
        if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            message: "Invaid email"
          })
        }
        if (password.length < 6) {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({
              message: "Password should be of at least 6 characters"
            })
        }
        const user = await User.create({
          username,
          email,
          password
        })
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(404).json({
            error: "No user found "
          })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
          user
        })
      } catch (error) {
        return next(error)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could `return` be used instead of `throw`?

Comment: `return` will just quit function when `throw` continues from `catch` block so you can tell the user that email already exists

Comment: Oh, well, I'm just trying to show the error message as alert message in my React component. If I send a response, I get the error in the error object. Is it possibe to throw a json response?

Comment: Oh yeah, it's working. throwing an error as response works. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Place it inside the `try` block before the logic for registration because the `find` has the potentials of throwing and error if the email does not exist.